# Difference between CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and GETDATE()

Tags: sql-server, ansi-sql

What is the difference between `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `GETDATE()` in SQL Server?

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is an ANSI SQL function whereas `GETDATE` is the T-SQL version of that same function.

One interesting thing to note however, is that `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is converted to `GETDATE()` when creating the object within SSMS. Both functions retrieve their value from the operating system in the same way.  There is no difference between the two, performance wise.

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is the recommended usage because it is portable to any ANSI compliant database, where as `GETDATE()` is not.

Comment: Is there any appreciable difference in performance? If I'm, say, generating log records by the thousands per second, I might care if `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` has some additional overhead associated with it.