# Create automatically generated timestamp column in table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to create a automatically generated timestamp column in table in Microsoft SQL Server 2019? Timestamp column should be automatically generated when I insert or update table.

In IBM Db2 database the syntax is the following:

```sql
    create table myschema.mytable (col1 int, col2 timestamp not null generated always for each row on update as row change timestamp
    insert into myschema.mytable (col1) values (1)
    update myschema.mytable set col1 = 2
```

After `insert`/`update` of column `col1`, column `col2` is automatically generated as current timestamp.

Comment: Assuming by timestamp you mean the current datetime, then `mycolumn datetime not null default(current_timestamp)`

Comment: If you mean a version field have a look at [rowversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) this is updated on every row change, but doesn't represent an actual date

Comment: If you need an actual datetime column (as opposed to a `rowversion`) you either need a trigger, or to run your update through a SP which adds it. There is no automated way other than `rowversion`.

Comment: I need to update timestamp column (datetime in MS-SQL language) also after every UPDATE statement. I know I can write trigger, but I would like to avoid additional complexity if possible.

Comment: Sorry, there is no automated way - trigger or SP.

Comment: @DaleK, thank you. I will go with trigger then.

Comment: @folow Please specify your decision as an update/addition to your question.

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft SQL Server you can try this code:

```sql
CREATE TABLE myschema.mytable
(
    col1 int, 
    col2 datetime not null default(current_timestamp)
)

INSERT INTO myschema.mytable(col1) VALUES (1)

UPDATE myschema.mytable SET col1 = 2

SELECT * FROM myschema.mytable
```

Update:
Let's create temporary table for test

```sql
DECLARE @mytable TABLE
(
    col1 int, 
    col2 datetime not null default(current_timestamp)
)

INSERT INTO @mytable(col1) VALUES (1)
SELECT * FROM @mytable

UPDATE @mytable SET col1 = 2
SELECT * FROM @mytable
```

Comment: @DaleK did not want to assign your comment in your answer, sorry! I hope I didn’t offend you. What should I do?

Comment: Keep in mind a default doesn't update on `updates` that is requested in the question

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts you mean `update` code line without `where` clause?

Comment: @timnavigate I mean the `col2` in your example will always have it's default value from the time it was inserted. When the row is updated, the default is not triggered, since there is already a value in col2

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts Yes that's right. In col2 will be set new value of current timestamp for each `insert` or `update` query. Everything is as it was in the question - `timestamp not null generated always for each row on update as row change timestamp`.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts I checked my example by creating a temporary table, six lines of `insert` queries and single line of `update` query - row values of `col2` always updated with every request. Or am I wrong about something?

Comment: @timnavigate - all good - carry on - its rare for people to use `current_timestamp` as most people use `getdate()` - which is what made me notice.

Comment: Ar yes, OP wants the timestamp column to update on update (as well as insert).

Comment: Yes, why I copied the version of @DaleK to my answer. `current_timestamp` is ANSI, same as in question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24226775/5309660

Comment: @timnavigate, in your example col2 timestamp field is only generated after INSERT, but I also need to change col2 timestamp field on every UPDATE. To simplify for every INSERT or UPDATE timestamp column col2 should be changed.

Comment: @folow I updated the answer: add test script to create a temporary table. Please try using this and let me know if this is right for you or not?

Comment: Tested this independently - like I thought, timestamp will written only while inserting row. Add some delay (`waitfor delay '00:00:03'`) between insert and update and you can see itself.

Comment: @timnavigate Are you sure that you tried it in MS SQL server? It is not working when I tried. I tried in 2019 version. Same as what arvo said..

Comment: @RamanSrinivasan Unfortunately, I do not have a Windows instance of MSSQL Server installed, but try to use [interactive test](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b947fe5ad6e4caac36a521be50c43c0e) in web

Comment: @timnavigate I checked in the fiddle. The timestamp is not changed after update. I tried with a 'waitfor' also with 5 seconds delay. Still the timestamp didnt change. Unfortunately i cant attach a screenshot here. But here is the https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8d42bbe6e1fa944d8c2589b5336f266f

Comment: I have tried this for "SQL Server 2019" on linux - column is not updated if I do UPDATE